# How to have text in center and image around it as shown in screenshot? (Image attached)

Tags: html, css, svg

I am converting an Illustrator design into HTML and CSS using Bootstrap framework. I am stuck on the part of design shown below:

[image: Illustrator Design]

I want the text surrounded by image as shown above.I can have these images separately and also one single image as I can export these from Illustrator according to the requirements. I can also export SVG image if required.What would be the best approach to achieve this task.

Comment: Having one single image is your best bet. Then you just have to position the text accordingly.

Comment: How will I make sure that the content does not overlap the image as the content can be dynamic later on.

Comment: By setting a specific width. @HarisAhmed

Comment: I am gonna try it. Thanks @NickRameau

Comment: I recommend you use a responsive framework by the way. @HarisAhmed

Comment: I am using Twitter Bootstrap to make the site responsive. What framework would you recommend? @NickRameau

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap is good. I personally use http://getskeleton.com @HarisAhmed

Comment: I am gonna check this out. Thanks @NickRameau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS, you can display the image as a `background-image` of a `<div>` *and* tailor the positioning of the heading and title within the same `<div>`.

**Markup:**

```
<div>
<h2>We Only Work With the Best</h2>
<p>We screen our coders&#39; social profiles like LinkedIn, GitHub and StackOverflow. After that, we only expose them to smaller tasks until they build up their reputation.</p>
</div>
```

**Styles:**

```
div {
text-align: center;
background-image: url('/work-with-the-best.png') no-repeat;
}

div h2 {
margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: What if my content needs to be dynamic and it shouldn't overlap the image but wrap around it. Is there anyway to do it using css background-image property?

Comment: I'm not sure I can picture what you are describing. Can you describe an example of dynamic content wrapping around an image? Thanks.

Comment: I am gonna convert this into WordPress theme. What I mean is if I change content from the back end and add some more text than it should not overlap the image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe position the text with relative and add a z-index to have it above the image.